# tinyMCE versus nicEdit?

Tags: jquery, css, tinymce, customization, nicedit

Has anyone tried both?

I started with nicEditor but am considering switching to TinyMCE because:

- nicEditor is no longer under development, and hence may have incompatibility issues with future CSS/HTML/jQuery versions
- little support
- not that many customization options, at least compared to tinyMCE.

Plus TinyMCE also has an Arabic plugin.
However I'm finding tinyMCE to be bulky and by the look of people's questions on it, it's not that easy to customize, and messes up the CSS.

My application requirements are to dynamically create, remove and save the contents of editable, draggable, resizable text boxes on a page.

Has anyone tried both, and what are your opinions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tinymce is suitable for your needs, but it might take some time to get into it. From my point of view tinymce is worth the effort (even works on iPads now). Tinymce comes with a load of functionality, but needs to be configured in order to work as desired (in case you wish some special functionality other than the default).

Answer (score 1):

I had used tinymce on windows, but there were issues on iPads (because of iframes) so  I used niceditor for ipad which uses content editable div.

Comment: yeah you have to make your own plugins for niceditor.Not tht stable as tinymce